# jQTouch - Cannot paste into input field: have anyone seen this?

Tags: jquery, html, jqtouch

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<input type="text" name="UPCtext" id="UPCtextBar" value="" placeholder="Type UPC number" class="UPCvalue"/>
```

There are no events bind()'s or live()'s associated with this input field.

If I remove jQTouch it works as it should, so, have anyone been through this problem?

Comment: I've also run into this problem. Pasting works fine on my iPhone but I cannot paste into a field when viewing the same page in my Mac's version of Safari. I'm also curious to know whether this is intentional and how it might be fixed or worked around.

Comment: Adding to this WebKit bug theory: I can paste on Firefox, but I can't on Safari and on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search for "jqtouch paste" revealed a jqTouch [issue](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=26) that suggests it may be a WebKit inheritance bug. No solution seems to be offered at this stage.

Comment: Thanks Reid!
I've found that issue after posting this question here, but I forgot to edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
function fixCopyPaste(el) {
    el.bind('paste', function(e) {
        var element = $(this).context;

        var text = $(this).val();
        var start = element.selectionStart;
        var pastedText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        $(this).val(text.substring(0, element.selectionStart)
            +pastedText
            +text.substring(element.selectionEnd, text.length));
        element.selectionStart = start+pastedText.length;
        element.selectionEnd = element.selectionStart;
    });
}
```

Call this function on the input element that you want to enable paste feature. E.g.:

```
fixCopyPaste($('#notes'));
```

It can probably be extented to handle more than one element.